# What is a 'sentisum_session' cookie?

Tags: cookies

What is a **'sentisum_session'** cookie? It appears under the list of cookies for our company's website - but I cannot figure out the provider and purpose of the cookie. It is set to expire 2 weeks after set / updated.

Comment: Its specific to your company's website. Search through your entire codeline for 'sentisum_session' to understand its purpose.

Comment: No it isn't something that is in our code. I can see the same cookie on other websites as well - mentioned on their cookie declaration page. But they have it as an 'Unclassified' cookie.

Answer (score 0):

The **sentisum_session** cookie is set by feefo, I'm not sure if it's related to the company sentisum who apply AI to analyse customer activity.

http://www.sentisum.com/

But feefo say that the data is anonymised and is GDPR compliant.